# Format the Rspec output in the terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, iterm2

I want to remove the milliseconds and the `begin transaction` and `rollback transaction` from the output

Also want to remove the database queries.

All  I want is the test itself.

Is there a way to get it done?

[image: Rspec Output]

Comment: Do you have this config in the spec_helper? `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Comment: added it, but now it looks worse @Vimsha

Comment: I wasn't asking you to add it. I was going to ask you to remove it if you have it

Answer (score 0):

After hours of looking for an answer it looks like the problem was with my Gemfile

I have the `rails_12factor` gem for Heroku and once I took it out, my tests went back to looking cleaner.

Now I just have it in my `:production` group

[image: Rspec Output]